# Str_replace not removing tags in message string

Tags: php, mysql, echo, str-replace

I echoing the contents of a table using foreach, the problem I am getting is the date is always at the top of the page, so when looking at my one line preview I just get the date and nothing more. If I remove the date it is fine and you can see the first line of the template. So I am trying to remove the date tag from the preview using for each.
I am using the following code, but it doesnt seem to be doing a lot, as far as I can see I have things right ?.

```
    echo '<div class="messagerow">';
// this pulls the message from the foreach above it
    $emlmsg = $row->emailformmessage;
// I am trying to remove the date by replacing it with the blank contents of this string value.
    $dateremove = '';
    // This is the str_replace that is supposed to remove the {date} tag along with the paragraph tags it is wrapped in.
$emlmsgfiltered = str_replace(array('<p>{date}</p>'), array($dateremove), $emlmsg);
// I then echo the filtered message here, minus the date....but its still there ??
echo $emlmsgfiltered;
echo '</div>';
```

Edit >>>>>>

```
 As requested, this is the html code

<p>{date}</p>

<p>Dear {name} thankyou for your order, if you need any more oil we will be happy to provide you with     a competitive quote.</p>

<p>Kind Regards</p>

{createdby}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP doesn't recognize Smarty tags (if that's what you're using)

Comment: why the (array) around the first value in str_replace()? are you supposed to be referencing an array element str_replace('<p>{date}</p>',$dateremove,$emlmsg)

Comment: Can you update the question with the HTML inside `$row->emailformmessage`? Also, you don't need an array!

Comment: Your code works fine with me, try this in your local server http://pastie.org/3191770. Put using arrays with `str_replace` is not needed, I just want to use your example.

Comment: This is a template by the looks of it. I think that you print the result after the variables substitution takes place. That means `{date}` is not in `$emlmsg` anymore, but its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry . should have been an ansewr, not a comment:

why the array around the first value in str_replace()? are you supposed to be referencing an array element

```
str_replace('<p>{date}</p>',$dateremove,$emlmsg)
```

Comment: Hi, no sorry, I thought that was meant to be like that

Comment: @IainSimpson: Arrays may be used to replace multiple values at once. E.g. as for German umlauts we often use `$text = str_replace(array('ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß'), array('ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'ss'), $text);`. So it should not make a difference, but of course easier is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `'<p>{date}</p>'` isn't being found. You can try to recreate the date here by typing something $date = date('Y-m-d') then `'<p>'.$date.'</p>'` or `"<p>$date</p>"`
However, the dates may not match up correctly in all cases.

You can also try to pull the date in from somewhere. That would be ideal.